# How to manually acknowledge on the listener?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm creating an application that reads from some source cluster/topic then does some processing on the message and finally writes to a destination cluster/topic. I would like to only move the offset when the message passes the processing phase. Do I just need to set `spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false`? Or do I need to also implement an AcknowledgingMessageListener or a ConsumerAwareMessageListener and do either consumer.commitSync() or ack.acknowledge()?

Created a plain MessageListener.

Comment: What is your code, please? Why don't you use a `@KafkaListener` with respective `Acknowledgment` argument? On the other hand: why don't use Kafka Streams since it sounds like you are in a consume-process-produce scenario.

Comment: You can only use streams if the source and destination cluster are the same.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've read that Streams will only work if both source and destination are on the same cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need at least an `AcknowledgingMessageListener` and set the container's `AckMode` to `MANUAL` or `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#committing-offsets